# Unable to import typescript file dynamically in deno exe

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, deno

I am trying to import a file from `aws` in exe using its public link based on some `user` `input` but unable to do so

e.g. I created my `exe` using the following command

```
deno compile --allow-all main.ts
```

User run this `exe` using command like `./exe --qId 345`. I parse this `qId` in `exe` and load some file from public link like this

```
let { runTestCases }  = await import ("https://test-cases.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/<qId>.ts")
```

But it gives me following error

```
TypeError: Module not found
at async getQuestionTestCaseFile (file:///F:/CodeQuotient/Deno_exe/deno/Controllers/question_controller.ts:47:37)
at async file:///F:/CodeQuotient/Deno_exe/deno/main.ts:14:1
```

It works fine when i run it using following command

```
deno run --allow-all main.ts
```

I want to know whether its possible or not to import module dynamically like this in exe.

If there is some other way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 0):

> As of Deno version `1.29.1`:

"Dynamic" [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) is not currently supported in `deno compile`.

This is a known issue and is being tracked at the following GitHub issue in the project's repository:

[denoland/deno#8655 - `deno compile` does not have dynamic import support](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/8655)

Comment: is there any other way of acheiving my use case or should i go for c++ or go?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74929008/unable-to-import-typescript-file-dynamically-in-deno-exe/74929396?noredirect=1#comment132240346_74929396) @Himanshu That depends on why you're bundling your source into a "compiled" executable. Why not just install `deno` in the runtime environment and run your source code? You can use dynamic import that way.